# Participants stopped in entry stage in amazon pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, aws-pinpoint

I have integrated amazon pinpoint with amazon connect to automate outbound campaign. But the problem that's happening, when the journey starts the participants are all in the "entry" stage (The first stage), and don't go to the next stage i.e.: to the call center (amazon connect).

For example, as you see here in the picture, the 1 participant is only in the "Entry" stage and didn't go to the next stage.

How Can I troubleshoot this problem? to figure out why the participants don't go to amazon connect.

[image]